# Why does my HTTPS request get disconnected on large files?

Tags: c++, https, arduino, esp32

I am making a `GET` request via HTTPS using HTTP 1.1 thru an *Ethernet connection* (no WiFi involved here).

My code is below.

For very small files (25B), the file is successfully downloaded. But is not downloaded when the file size increases (20K or 2MB), the connection is closed quite quickly.

So, my question is: how can I make a download of a "large" file?

My code runs on an ESP32.

```cpp
#include <EthernetUdp.h>

#include <EthernetLarge.h>
#include <SSLClient.h>

// Choose the analog pin to get semi-random data from for SSL
// Pick a pin that's not connected or attached to a randomish voltage source
const int rand_pin = A5;
 
// Initialize the SSL client library
// We input an EthernetClient, our trust anchors, and the analog pin
EthernetClient base_client;
SSLClient client(base_client, TAs, (size_t)TAs_NUM, rand_pin);

void NanoEthernet::httpsGet(
    char const *hostname, char const *path, 
    byte *buffer, size_t bufferCapacity, 
    size_t &bodyLength, bool &bufferOverflows,
    void (*downloadChunkCallback)(byte * buffer, size_t bufferReadCount, size_t contentLength)
    ) {

    log("Time is: %d %d %d %02d:%02d:%02d", day(), month(), year(), hour(), minute(), second());

    char const * subModule = "httpsGet: ";
    log("%sbegin %s%s…",subModule, hostname, path);
    
    // === if you get a connection, report back via serial:
    if (!client.connect(hostname, 443)) {
        // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
        error("%sconnection failed", subModule);
        return false;
    }



    success("%sConnected!",subModule);
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.printf("GET %s HTTP/1.1", path);             client.println();
    client.printf("Host: %s", hostname);                client.println();
    // client.println("Connection: keep-alive");            client.println();
    // client.println("Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100");    client.println();
    //client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

    //while(client.connected() && !client.available()) delay(1); //waits for data

    // success("%sSent query headers (connected:%d)",
    //  subModule,
    //  client.connected()
    // );

    
    /// Body counter
    int bodyCounter = 0;

    /// Chunk counter
    int chunkReadCount = 0;

    /// Whether to read response header?
    bool readResponseHeader = true;
    byte *p = buffer;

    int contentLength = 0;

    const unsigned timeoutNoData = 10*1000; // 10 seconds
    unsigned long long lastTimeNoData = millis();

    unsigned waitForConnection = 10;

    while (true) {
        // log("%sResponse: connected: %d | readResponseHeader: %d", 
        //  subModule,
        //  client.connected(),
        //  readResponseHeader
        // );
        if (!client.connected()) {
            delay(1);
            error("%sNo more connected, aborting", subModule);
            if (waitForConnection-- <= 0)
                continue;
            else
                break;
        }

        if (!client.available()) {
            delay(1);

            // == Still reading the header then continue, otherwise hanle timeout
            if (!readResponseHeader) {
                if (millis() - lastTimeNoData >= timeoutNoData) {
                    if (contentLength==0) {
                        log("%sNo more data are available after %d seconds timeout", 
                            subModule,
                            timeoutNoData/1000
                        );
                    }
                    else { 
                        error("%sNo more data are available timeout", subModule);
                    }
                    // == Stopping the connection
                    break;
                }
            }

            //log(">.");
            continue;
        }   
        lastTimeNoData = millis();

    
        // = Skip response header
        if (readResponseHeader) {
            const String header = client.readStringUntil('\n'); // End of line is "\r\n"

            log("%sResponse headers: %s", subModule, header.c_str());

            const int nextData = client.peek();
            // End of stream?
            if (nextData==-1) {
                error("%sEnd of stream (received data -1) while reading headers");
                break;
            }

            const char nextChar = char(nextData);
            //log("Response headers: => next char is %d 0x%02x (%c)", nextChar, nextChar, nextChar);
            // == End of headers? (empty line)      
            if (nextChar == '\r') {
                // Actually read the end of line
                client.read();  // eat \r
                client.read();  // eat \n
                //log("End of response header, starting to read response body…");
                readResponseHeader=false;
            }
            else {

                char const *headerString = "Content-Length: ";
                const int headerStringLength = 16;
                if (header.startsWith(headerString)) {
                    const String sContentLength = header.substring(headerStringLength);
                    contentLength = header.substring(headerStringLength).toInt();
                    //log("Read Content-Length: string: '%s'| int: %d bytes", sContentLength.c_str(), byteCountToRead);
                }
            }
            continue;
        }

        const int data = client.read(); //gets byte from ethernet buffer
        // == End of stream?
        if (data==-1) {
            log("%sEnd of stream (data received: -1)",subModule);
            break;
        }

        // == Keep the actual byte
        const byte b = byte(data);

        #if LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG
        //log(">%02x (%d)", b, bodyCounter);
        log(">%02x ", b);
        #endif

        *p++ = b;
        bodyCounter++;
        chunkReadCount++;

        // = When no chunk callback, overflow means stop reading
        if (downloadChunkCallback==NULL) {
            // == If buffer overflows, stop
            if (bodyCounter >= bufferCapacity) {

                bufferOverflows = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // = But when chunk callback has been provided, pass it the 
        // chunk, rewind the buffer and continue
        else {
                // == If buffer overflows, stop
            if (chunkReadCount >= bufferCapacity) {
                downloadChunkCallback(buffer, chunkReadCount, contentLength);
                // Now rewind the chunk to the satrt of the buffer prior to 
                // continue reading the reponsse body
                chunkReadCount = 0;
                p = buffer;
            }
        }

        // == We read everything?
        if (contentLength>0) {
            if (bodyCounter>=contentLength) {
                log("%sEnd of stream (received ontentLength bytes)", subModule);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    

    // = When chunk callback, pass it the potential remaining chunk
    if(downloadChunkCallback!=NULL 
    && chunkReadCount>0) {
        downloadChunkCallback(buffer, chunkReadCount, contentLength);
    }

    // == Write the length we read
    bodyLength = bodyCounter;
    
    #if LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG
    log("");
    log("%s: did the get and read %d bytes", subModule, bodyCounter);
    #endif
    
    client.stop();
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Read [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4). A `Content-Length` header is not the only way to determine the end of a response. For instance, you are not handling `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` at all. What do the response headers actually look like when a download "succeeds" vs "fails"? Is there a reason why you are using `SSLClient` to implement HTTPS manually, instead of using an actual HTTPS client library?

Comment: If you have a reference about an HTTPS client lib that does the thing, I take it :-)

Comment: [ESP32 HTTP Requests using HTTPClient Library](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-https-requests/#esp32-https-requests-httpclient)

Comment: first test `available()`, then `connected()`, because there can be still buffered data. https://github.com/OPEnSLab-OSU/SSLClient/issues/43

Comment: @RemyLebeau The fact is that I sue Ethernet connection (not WiFi )

Comment: it is possible to use the W5500 as network interface for the esp32 LwIP and the WiFi library, but there is no Arduino library for that. it was used here https://github.com/khoih-prog/WebServer_ESP32_SC_W5500/tree/main/src/w5500 as part of the WebServer library

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca [ESP32 HTTPClient source code](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/HTTPClient), I'm sure you can tweak it to use an Ethernet client instead of a WiFi client.

Comment: Try using HTTP 1.0 to avoid the response chunking: `client.printf("GET %s HTTP/1.0", path);`

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution.

The point is that, of course, I  don't have 2MB of free memory (actually the ESP32 is a 320KB RAM microcontroller), so the point is to ask the server to send a series of very small chunks the we process to append them in a continuous way down to a file on the flash.

The first candidate I thought of was the `chunk transfert encoding/ but alas, is up to the server to select such a mode and because the remote server is actually Azure storage, no hunk mode was proposed.

This is the reason why I called back to the `Range` mode: you simply specify in the headers `Range: bytes: <start>-<end>` to receive the corresponding bit of data.

So I ended up by opening the HTTPS connection, then, with the keep alive connection I make a series of `GET` for which I ask for a sliding window of data.

The code snippet is as follows:

```cpp
/// @brief Writes the GET on [path] and write mandatory constant headers
/// @param host The host name
/// @param path The path of he document to get
static void httpsGetWriteMandatoryHeaders(char const *hostname, char const * path) {
    client.printf("GET %s HTTP/1.1", path);             client.println();
    client.printf("Host: %s", hostname);                client.println();

    client.printf("Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate");    client.println();
    client.printf("Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); client.println();

}

bool NanoEthernet :: httpsGet(
    char const *hostname, char const *path, 
    byte *buffer, size_t bufferCapacity, 
    size_t &bodyLength, bool &bufferOverflows,
    void (*downloadChunkCallback)(byte * buffer, size_t bufferReadCount, size_t contentLength),
    bool verbose
    ) {

    log("Time is: %d %d %d %02d:%02d:%02d", day(), month(), year(), hour(), minute(), second());

    char const * subModule = "httpsGet: ";
    
    if (verbose) log("%sbegin %s%s…",subModule, hostname, path);
    
    // === if you get a connection, report back via serial:
    if (!client.connect(hostname, 443)) {
        // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
        error("%sconnection failed", subModule);
        return false;
    }

    unsigned chunkIndex = 0;

    success("%sConnected!",subModule);
    // Make a HTTP request:
    httpsGetWriteMandatoryHeaders(hostname, path);
    client.printf("Range: bytes=%d-%d", chunkIndex*bufferCapacity, (chunkIndex+1)*bufferCapacity);              client.println();

    #if COMPUTE_CHECKSUM
    // Reset checksum variable.
    checksum32 = 0;
    #endif
    // Counter for each chunck 
    int messageCounter = 0;
    /// Body counter
    int bodyCounter = 0;

    /// Chunk counter
    int chunkReadCount = 0;

    /// Whether to read response header?
    bool readResponseHeader = true;
    byte *p = buffer;

    // Length of single chunck
    int contentLength = 0; 

    // // Length of full body (File to transfer)
    // int bodyLength = 0; 

    const unsigned timeoutNoData = 10*1000; // 10 seconds
    unsigned long long lastTimeNoData = millis();

    unsigned waitForConnection = 10;

    while (true) {
        
        if (!client.connected()) {
            delay(1);
            error("%sNo more connected, aborting", subModule);
            if (waitForConnection-- <= 0)
                continue;
            else
                break;
        }

        if (!client.available()) {
            delay(1);

            // == Still reading the header then continue, otherwise hanle timeout
            if (!readResponseHeader) {
                if (millis() - lastTimeNoData >= timeoutNoData) {
                    if (contentLength==0) {
                        if (verbose) 
                        log("%sNo more data are available after %d seconds timeout", 
                            subModule,
                            timeoutNoData/1000
                        );
                    }
                    else { 
                        error("%sNo more data are available timeout", subModule);
                    }
                    // == Stopping the connection
                    break;
                }
            }

            //log(">.");
            continue;
        }   
        lastTimeNoData = millis();

    
        // = Skip response header
        if (readResponseHeader) {
            const String header = client.readStringUntil('\n'); // End of line is "\r\n"
            #if LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG
            if((chunkIndex%20)==0){
                if (verbose) log("%sResponse headers: %s", subModule, header.c_str());
            }
            #endif  

            const int nextData = client.peek();
            // End of stream?
            if (nextData==-1) {
                error("%sEnd of stream (received data -1) while reading headers");
                break;
            }

            const char nextChar = char(nextData);
            //log("Response headers: => next char is %d 0x%02x (%c)", nextChar, nextChar, nextChar);
            // == End of headers? (empty line)      
            if (nextChar == '\r') {
                // Actually read the end of line
                client.read();  // eat \r
                client.read();  // eat \n
                //log("End of response header, starting to read response body…");
                readResponseHeader=false;
            }
            else {

                // == Repsonse code

                //HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
                char const *headerString = "HTTP/1.1 ";
                size_t headerStringLength = 9;

                if (header.startsWith(headerString)) {
                    const String sCode = header.substring(headerStringLength);
                    const unsigned code = header.substring(headerStringLength).toInt();
                    switch (code/100) {
                        case 2:
                            if (verbose) success("Response code: %d", code);
                            continue;

                        // == All others are considered as errors
                        case 3: warn("Response code: code %d is not handled specifically", code);

                        default:
                            error("Response code not 2xx: code %d, extiting", code);
                            client.stop();
                            return false;
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                // == Content length

                headerString = "Content-Length: ";
                headerStringLength = 16;

                if (header.startsWith(headerString)) {
                    const String sContentLength = header.substring(headerStringLength);
                    contentLength = header.substring(headerStringLength).toInt();
                    //log("Read Content-Length: string: '%s'| int: %d bytes", sContentLength.c_str(), byteCountToRead);
                }
                else if (header.startsWith("Content-Range:") && bodyLength==0){
                    const String content_size = header.substring(header.indexOf("/")+1);
                    bodyLength = content_size.toInt();
                    if (verbose) log("body has a length of: %d bytes",bodyLength);
                }
            }
            continue;
        }

        const int data = client.read(); //gets byte from ethernet buffer
        // == End of stream?
        if (data==-1) {
            if (verbose) log("%sEnd of stream (data received: -1)",subModule);
            break;
        }

        // == Keep the actual byte
        const byte b = byte(data);

        #if LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG
        log(">%02x ", b);
        #endif

        *p++ = b;
        bodyCounter++;
        chunkReadCount++;
        messageCounter++;
        
        #if COMPUTE_CHECKSUM
        checkSum32(data); // Updating checksum 32
        #endif

        // = When no chunk callback, overflow means stop reading
        if (downloadChunkCallback==NULL) {
            // == If buffer overflows, stop
            if (bodyCounter >= bufferCapacity) {

                bufferOverflows = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // = But when chunk callback has been provided, pass it the 
        // chunk, rewind the buffer and continue
        else {
                // == If buffer overflows, stop
            if (chunkReadCount >= bufferCapacity) {
                downloadChunkCallback(buffer, chunkReadCount, bodyLength);
                // Now rewind the chunk to the satrt of the buffer prior to 
                // continue reading the reponsse body
                chunkReadCount = 0;
                p = buffer;

            }
        }

        // == We read everything?
        if (contentLength>0) {
            if (messageCounter>=contentLength) {
                #if LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG
                    log("%sEnd of stream (received contentLength bytes)", subModule);
                #endif
                client.flush();

                /// Ask for the new chunk
                if(chunkIndex*bufferCapacity<bodyLength){
                    
                    ++chunkIndex;
                
                    if (verbose) log("Asking for new chunk #%d of %d bytes max", chunkIndex, bufferCapacity);
                    
                    httpsGetWriteMandatoryHeaders(hostname, path);
                    if ((chunkIndex+1)*bufferCapacity<bodyLength){
                        client.printf("Range: bytes=%d-%d", chunkIndex*bufferCapacity+1, (chunkIndex+1)*bufferCapacity);        client.println();
                    }
                    else{
                        client.printf("Range: bytes=%d-%d", chunkIndex*bufferCapacity+1, bodyLength);       client.println();
                    }

                    client.println();
                    readResponseHeader=true;
                    messageCounter = 0;
                    while (!client.available()&&client.connected()) delay(1);
                }
                else{
                    if (verbose) success("All the data is well received");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    // = When chunk callback, pass it the potential remaining chunk
    if(downloadChunkCallback!=NULL 
    && chunkReadCount>0) {
        downloadChunkCallback(buffer, chunkReadCount, bodyLength);
    }

    // == Write the length we read
    bodyLength = bodyCounter;
    
    // #if LOG_LEVEL >= LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG
    log("");
    log("%s: did the get and read %d bytes", subModule, bodyCounter);
    // #endif
    
    client.stop();
    
    #if COMPUTE_CHECKSUM
    if (verbose) log("------------- The checksum32 is %d -----------------", checksum32);
    #endif
    
    return true;    
}
```